# Timer for a game generates random numbers instead of counting down

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android game. The main game screen has a countdown timer and when it reaches zero the game is over. The code below works the first time the user plays a level. However, approximately every fifth time the user plays a second level, the numbers produced become random, for example, it just started from 30 and then went to -15. Can anyone suggest any reason for it doing this?

```
public class Timer1 {
int time = 120;
int counter = 0;
int startTime = 30; // Change to 2 minutes
Timer timer;

boolean end = false;

World world = new World();

public Timer1() {

}

public void subtractTime() {
    startTime = startTime - 15; // Knock off 15 seconds for hint
}

public int getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    time = 120;
    startTime = 30;
    end = false;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            counter++;
            time = startTime - counter;
            if (time == 0) {
                world.gameOver = true;
                end = true;
                timerCancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

public void timerCancel() {
    timer.cancel();
}

}
```

Comment: is the TimerTask of type thread? then it should be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset your counter to 0, if you aren't instantiating this class every time then that number just goes up and up.

```
public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    time = 120;
    startTime = 30;
    counter = 0; // NEW CODE
    end = false;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            counter++;
            time = startTime - counter;
            if (time == 0) {
                world.gameOver = true;
                end = true;
                timerCancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

but what you are doing is calling startTimer, but your 'resetting the timer'. i.e. resetting all your variables *then* you are starting the timer. It would be easier if you just did `new Timer1().startTimer()` everytime, it would also make your code easier to read an maintain.

Also if your maths is off and time doesn't equal 0 but is **less than 0 then your timer carries on**. Be careful. `if (time == 0) {`

Try this:

```
 if (time <= 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made the changes you suggested and it works. I really appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting the `counter`. Since you end the level if `time == 0` the terminating condition is not reached.

Additionally, you are assuming that the `TimerTask` is called every second, on the mark. Generally, this assumption is false. If your game needs the CPU time the `TimerTask`'s execution may be delayed. Therefore consider remembering the system time on start (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) and check on each successive call to the `TimerTask` how much time has passed and decide whether the time is up based on that, instead of the counter.

Comment: Thank you. I did try the approach of getting the system time, etc. but just couldn't get it to work. If the time isn't exact it doesn't matter so I won't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be a lot easier if you use a `Handler` and the `Handler.postDelayed` method.

Have a look at the [Android Docu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: The two Android books I have read don't mention Handler. I am going to have to find out more. Thanks for you help.